# Adjective for "lacking/losing/wanting of elasticity/stretchiness after too much stretching" to describe originally elastic/stretchy things?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When certain elastic or stretchy objects are overstretched, especially in prolonged periods, they may lose elasticity altogether and cannot return to their unstretched state. What would be an adjective to describe that lack of stretchiness or elasticity?

> The waistband of my old pants is worn and _____.
>
> This spring was stretched so often that it became _____.
>
> These ____ rubber bands are unusable.

Comment: It seems like there should be a word for this, but I'm not sure there is. The deleted answer from @fev seems like it might be best, even though it's not as specific as you want.

Answer (score 3):

A word that covers this, but also covers many other circumstances where something had lost usefulness or function, is **spent**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/spent)
> *spent*:
> Something that is spent has been used so that it no longer has any power or effectiveness

A more specific but more technical term is **inelastic**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inelastic)
> *inelastic*:
> not changing much, or not allowing much change

Hence, in physics and engineering we have:

> [HSTutorial](https://www.hstutorial.com/elasticity/)
> *Inelastic Material*
> It is/they are material that does not return to its original shape and size after deformation.

Answer (score 2):

My mother used to say it was "shot," and that always made sense to me. She was from the South; maybe it's a regional thing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to describe rubber that has lost its elasticity is to say that it has

> **perished**

(See [example 5 in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perished).)

However I personally would only use this term in relation to rubber that had lost its elasticity with age, and I suspect the chemical transformation in this case is different from that caused by stretching. I have not yet been been able to find technical descriptors that distinguish the two.

You would certainly *not* use this term for metallic springs, where I imagine something akin to [*‘work hardening’*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_hardening) is occurring.

Comment: Agreed. The elastomer on a u-seal or o-ring can "perish".

Answer (score 0):

There's a homely phrase that describes this situation: **all stretched out**.

> These exercise pants are not in great condition as you stated in the product listing. The elastic waistband is *all stretched out* :-(

The elastic no longer contracts and won't pull tight around the waist. The exercise pants fall down.

Compare: https://www.reddit.com/r/uniqlo/comments/jie7dy/eazy_jeans_are_all_stretched_out_in_the_waistbum/

Answer (score 0):

Rubber and springs are quite different. As far as rubber is concerned, there is

**Perished** (adj) OED:

> **2.b. Of rubber or a similar material, or an article made from it: having lost its characteristic elasticity and become weak, sticky,
> etc.**
>
> 1922 After a time, vulcanised rubber tends to harden, cracks appear on
> the surface when the article is bent or stretched, and eventually the
> rubber becomes rotten and ‘perished’. *H. P. Stevens in S. Morgan,
> Prep. Plantation Rubber xxi. 306*
>
> 1967 Under the more severe running conditions.., casing compounds
> based conventionally on natural rubber would reach a perished
> condition in a relatively short time. *B. N. Leyland & J. T. Watts in
> J. A. Brydson, Devel. with Nat. Rubber v. 67*

You will have to be more specific with "metal springs" which compress, extend, and flex. I don't think that there is one word that describes the loss of elasticity in all materials and items.

Answer (score -1):

> elastic failure
> elastic failurei′las·tik ′fāl·yər
> Failure of a body to recover its original size and shape after a stress is removed.

https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/elastic+failure

Comment: Keyword: "adjective"

Comment: So fine. Failed.  Elasticity is a property of, e.g., rubber.

Comment: "Elasticity is a property of, e.g., rubber." That is not relevant. I know what it means, I use this very word multiple times in my question. I'm not asking you to give me the definition of "elasticity".